# Understanding Quake I Timer

Tags: c

Here is a snippet of code from Quake I.

```
    LARGE_INTEGER   PerformanceFreq;
    unsigned int    lowpart, highpart;
    OSVERSIONINFO   vinfo;

    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency (&PerformanceFreq))
        Sys_Error ("No hardware timer available");

    // get 32 out of the 64 time bits such that we have around 1 microsecond resolution
    lowpart = (unsigned int)PerformanceFreq.LowPart;
    highpart = (unsigned int)PerformanceFreq.HighPart;
    lowshift = 0;

    while (highpart || (lowpart > 2000000.0))
    {
        lowshift++;
        lowpart >>= 1;
        lowpart |= (highpart & 1) << 31;
        highpart >>= 1;
    }
```

The comment indicates that they are reducing the 64 bit `PerformanceFreq` to 32 bits and that the resolution is about 1 microsecond (the default resolution of QueryPerformanceFrequency is 1 second).

I understand what the code is doing generally, but I don't know what `(lowpart > 2000000.0)` is meant to be doing or why it's there. I think it's related to ensuring the resolution is about 1 microsecond.

When I run this code through the debugger the `lowpart` is shifted 3 times meaning that the resolution is actually 1s / 2^3 - 0.125s or 125 milliseconds and not 1 microsecond. The documentation for `QueryPerformanceFrequency` says that the result is hardware dependent so I don't see how a constant value `200000.0` could work unless you were making an assumption for the result based on modern hardware of the time.

Is this code wrong about the resolution or am I missing something?